# How to fix the problem with Keycloak Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

I am using Keycloak for securing Spring boot application. In my case, I use Keycloak to secure microservices. The services call one-another. For calling services, I am using Keycloak's client_credentials grant. I created a client and configured spring boot with Keycloak properties. Everything works fine but except for one thing. When I send a GET request to secured endpoints, I am getting the right response. But, If I send a POST request, I am getting an Error. The error is

```
"timestamp": "2019-04-17T11:38:39.737+0000",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Access to the requested resource has been denied",
"path": "/v1/users/register"
```

I have tried to configure Spring boot with

```
##-------------- Keycloak configuration ----------------------------
keycloak.realm=phantomwallet
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth/
keycloak.resource=wallet_client
keycloak.credentials.secret=ebb59830-2abc-4a92-9d67-b6bfb3eb3bd2
keycloak.bearer-only=true
#keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.security-constraints[0].auth-roles[0]=client_role
keycloak.security-constraints[0].auth-roles[1]=basic_role
keycloak.security-constraints[0].security- 
collections[0].patterns[0]=/*
```

Comment: Try to add **logging.level.org.keycloak=DEBUG** in your properties file and check the SpringBoot log afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I have already solved it. The problem was with _csrf_. Should be disabled it, otherwise, Spring security checks _csrf_  and reject it if a request is sent by not a browser devices. Besides that, I disabled _auth_roles_ .

Comment: How did you disable auth-roles?